# Move CSV file to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, csv, csv-import

I have CSV file on the first row I have

```
offerId;monthlyFee;newContractsForMonth;sameContractsForMonth;CancelledContractsForMonth
```

From the second row to the end I have two columns - for example:

```
Second row first column 1;38 Second row second column 66;98;68;28
Third row first column 2;10 third row second column 11;99;180;15
```

and so on

I wrote this code

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@path))
{
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config))
    {
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<OfferWithoutInteger>().ToList();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            record.offerId = Regex.Replace(record.offerId, ",", "");
            record.monthlyFee = Regex.Replace(record.monthlyFee, ",", "");
            record.newContractsForMonth = Regex.Replace(record.newContractsForMonth, ",", "");
            record.sameContractsForMonth = Regex.Replace(record.sameContractsForMonth, ",", "");
            record.CancelledContractsForMonth = Regex.Replace(record.CancelledContractsForMonth, ",", "");
        }

        await this._context.AddRangeAsync(records);
        await this._context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

and manage to put my data into database with string format. My question is how to merge the two columns and how to convert the data from string to int.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you create a class with integers instead of strings? (a Offer_with_Integers)?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the actual file?

Comment: Yes, that was the first I tried but in order to convert the data type I should merge the two columns because when I set the delimiter to ";" when the two columns concat they give me data like 45,15 but it must be 4515

Comment: https://ibb.co/Jm7wk2D Yes, this is sample

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I used

```
Map(row => row.CustomClassField).Name("CSVColumnName").Convert(row => int.Parse(row.Row.GetField("CSVColumnName").Replace(",","")));
```

Bellow is the code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var @path = @"pathToFile";
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { Delimiter = ";", Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

            var offersWithIntegerValues = new OfferWithIntegers();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@path))
            {
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config))
                {
                    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<OffersWithIntegersMap>();
                    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<OfferWithIntegers>().ToList();                        
                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        public class OffersWithIntegersMap : ClassMap<OfferWithIntegers>
        {
            public OffersWithIntegersMap()
            {
                Map(row => row.offerId).Name("offerId").Convert(row => int.Parse(row.Row.GetField("offerId").Replace(",","")));
                Map(row => row.monthlyFee).Name("monthlyFee").Convert(row => int.Parse(row.Row.GetField("monthlyFee").Replace(",","")));
                Map(row => row.newContractsForMonth).Name("newContractsForMonth").Convert(row => int.Parse(row.Row.GetField("newContractsForMonth").Replace(",","")));
                Map(row => row.sameContractsForMonth).Name("sameContractsForMonth").Convert(row => int.Parse(row.Row.GetField("sameContractsForMonth").Replace(",","")));
                Map(row => row.CancelledContractsForMonth).Name("CancelledContractsForMonth").Convert(row => int.Parse(row.Row.GetField("CancelledContractsForMonth").Replace(",","")));
            }
        }
```